# Error when formatting Report Value

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer, rdlc

I have an RDLC report where the text field is set to:

```
=UCase(Fields!Region.Value)
```

When i run the report, the output returns

```
#VALUE!
```

Funny thing is, when i replace the expression with `=Fields!Region.Value`, the correct string value is displayed on the report

Has anyone come across this issue? Can anyone shed some light and help a man out?

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly convert the value to a string and then us ucase. SSRS does not always handle conversions gracefully and you have to tell it want to do.

```
=UCase(CStr(Fields!Region.Value))
```

That should get you what you are looking for.

Comment: I was just about to post this.  Good stuff.

Comment: @SonnyChilds This one is officially burned into the back of my head because I spent 3 or 4 hours trying to figure this exact thing out when I got into SSRS.